# How to create a 2D-Array of chars given a string?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, graph, maze

Given this string (or any string): "# ####\n# #\n# ## #\n# #\n### ##\n", 
how can I I'm working on a shortest path finding maze solver for my data structures and algorithms class. Given this string (or any string), how can I make a 2D array from it? That way, I can just loop through the 2d array and if its a whitespace, I can make a new vertex.

For example, this

"# ####\n# #\n# ## #\n# #\n### ##\n"

should be stored in the 2D array like so:

```
 # ####

 #    #

 # ## #

 #    #

 ### ##
```

I tried implementing this but it didn't print out the right thing.

```
char ** grid;
for(int i = 0; i < maze.size(); i++){
    grid[i] = new char[numCols];
    for(int j = 0; j != '\n'; j++){
        cin >> grid[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: *should be stored in the 2D array like so:* This is **not** an array. How many elements does the second row have?

Comment: The second row (and all rows) would have 6 items in this case. There would bet two '#' and four whitespaces.

Comment: And how come `#_#` (1 space) is translated as `#____#` (4 spaces)and not something like `#_#   `(1+3 spaces)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure that you deal with a fixed number of lines. The example below is conservative, it assumes that you do not know in advance the number of lines and that each line could have different length, hence it uses a vector of `vector` of `string`.

You can replace this with arrays if you know the size in advance. Comments should make the behavior clear.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   const char *s = "# ####\n#    #\n# ## #\n#    #\n### ##\n";

   istringstream is(s);  // associate the input string with an input stream

   vector<string> result;  // use string for each line because a vector of characters is a string

   string line;
   while(getline(is, line)) // use stream library to read until next \n character
        result.push_back(line);  // add line

   // demonstrate results
   for (size_t i = 0; i < result.size(); ++i) {
       for (size_t j = 0; j < result[i].length(); ++j)
           cout << result[i][j];
       cout << "\n";
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is very helpful. I ran it on a online compiler very quickly and everything printed out correctly except the 2nd and 4th row. The second hashtag is in the 3rd column when it should be in the last column. Also, why did you use const char *s to store the string?

Comment: If you want it in the last column, then you need to add more spaces. The second line instance of being `"#.#\n"` should be `"# ....#\n`, unless there is a grammar rules in these things which you have not specified. Note that I replaced spaces with dots in this message, otherwise the message does not render correctly. `const char *` is just the type for C-style raw strings.

Comment: Ohhh I see. I just realized that the I didn't copy the string correctly so the spaces are off. But it works now. Is there a way to access individual elements by s[i][j]?

Comment: Also, how could I use the traditional nested for loops instead of the range-based for loops?

Comment: Yes, you can use `v[i][j]`. If you know the size in advance, do not use `vector`, a C-style array will do, it will simplify the example quite a bit. Yes, you could use normal loops. I see you are new to this web site. If you think this is the correct answer, you may consider up-voting it and marking it as correct.

Comment: Yes, I figured out the number of rows and columns which allowed to use traditional iterator for-loops. Once again, thank you so much for your help and I will up-vote your response and mark it as correct.

Comment: vector<char> is essentially a std::string